# Understanding the Poisson Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation, harmonic-functions

This is a fragment of my complex analysis book, when he explains how to solve the Dirichlet problem

> Theorem. Let $U(\phi)$ continuous for $0\leq \phi \leq 2\pi$. Then the function $$u(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} U(\phi) \frac{R^2 - |z|^2}{|Re^{i\phi}-z|^2}d\phi $$ is harmonic in $|z|<R$ and $$\lim_{z \rightarrow Re^{i\phi}}u(z)=U(\phi).$$
>   Proog. [...] given $\epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that $|U(\phi)-U(\alpha)|<\epsilon$ when $|\phi - \alpha| < \delta$. Then by the Poisson kernel property and the fact that $U$ is $2\pi$-periodic
>   $$|u(z)-U(\alpha)|= \left| \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} (U(\phi) - U(\alpha)) \frac{R^2 - |z|^2}{|Re^{i\phi}-z|^2}d\phi  \right| \leq  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left| (U(\phi) - U(\alpha)) \right| \frac{R^2 - |z|^2}{|Re^{i\phi}-z|^2}d\phi \leq \epsilon + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\delta \leq|\phi - \alpha|\leq\pi} \left| U(\phi) - U(\alpha) \right| \frac{R^2 - |z|^2}{|Re^{i\phi}-z|^2}d\phi.$$ Now, if $|\arg(z)-\alpha|<\delta /2$ and $|\phi - \alpha|\geq \delta$, then $$|Re^{i\phi}-z|\geq R\sin(\delta/2)$$

I can't understand where it comes the bound $$|Re^{i\phi}-z|\geq R\sin(\delta/2)$$

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider the case $\alpha+\delta  \le \phi  \le \alpha +\pi/2$ for simplicity (we can do similarly even in other cases). See the diagram below. In the diagram $$
\left|Re^{i\phi }-z\right|=\text{the length of the black-colored segment},$$
which is greater than the length of the red-colored segment since $|\arg(z)-\alpha|<\delta /2.$
The length of the red-colored segment is equal to $$
R\sin \left(\phi -\alpha -\frac{\delta}{2}\right).$$ 
Since $\phi -\alpha -\frac{\delta}{2}\ge (\alpha +\delta) -\alpha -\frac{\delta}{2}=\frac{\delta}{2}
$, we see $$
\sin \left(\phi -\alpha -\frac{\delta}{2}\right)\ge \sin \left(\frac{\delta}{2}\right)
.$$
Therefore we have $$
\left|Re^{i\phi }-z\right|\ge R\sin \left(\phi -\alpha -\frac{\delta}{2}\right)\ge R\sin \left(\frac{\delta}{2}\right)
.$$
Of course $R\sin \left(\frac{\delta}{2}\right)$ is the length of the blue-colored segment.

[image]